# How can I learn best practices about blob storage on azure?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, remote-blob-store

Developed a file structure. It's run without azure. Need to provide same solution on azure but I want to learn blobs storage deeply first.  Reading performance is very important for me. And memory usage too. It's a larger than download and read on memory and reading positions is relative but sequential from position zero to the end of file(not the entire file: with seeking)

What is the best source?

Answer (score 0):

Bing seems to give a good list to start with:

- https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/8-essential-best-practices-in-windows-azure-blob-storage/
- http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/windows-azure-storage-best-practices/
- http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-performance/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'am already searched articles and blogs but it is not insufficient for me. I want to ensure all thinks about that apis. For example; OpenRead opens the stream for reading but its uses 4 mb buffer.